# How to implement Oauth login in android+ spring boot+ security

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I am trying to implement sns login with Spring Security. The api server is spring-boot and the front is android and iOS.

From my understanding, it seems that spring-security-oauth-client supports the process of issuing an access token with server side rendering. (authentication code grant or implicit grant ..etc)

This is where my troubles begin.

First of all, I want to use OpenId Connect because I know that authentication should not be processed with oauth's access token.

Because android needs to use the sdk, the front (android) issues the idToken and gives it to the backend server.

So I wanted to implement it using the oauth2 function supported by spring-security, but I couldn't find a good way. So the following question arose:

1. Can it be implemented with the oauth-support function of spring-security?

So, I am trying to process authentication by creating an Authentication Provider for each oauth provider through a custom filter that directly extends OncePerRequestFilter.

Another question arises here.

2. Is there any difference between implementing the filter directly in spring-security and performing authentication in the controller of the spring container? performance or other aspects

thank you.

Comment: It seems unlikely that the android app is issuing the token. Is it perhaps retrieving the token from an authorization server (for example Google)?

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana
 oh .. when i say issue, i mean that i got the idToken from authorization server(google ..) 
the document is here https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth

Comment: Then it seems your Spring application is an OAuth 2.0 Resource Server. You can find instructions setting up a Resource Server using Spring Security [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html). Spring Security has built-in support for Resource Servers, so there is not need to create a custom filter, or perform authentication in the Controller.

Comment: Is oauth login and resource server different in spring security?
Then, can I immediately verify and use JWT (IdToken) as a resource server function?

Comment: Yes they are different and yes the resource server will validate the JWT.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
Another question, is this a different feature from OpenID Connect 1.0 UserService in security oauth-login? Is there any way to map the userInfoEndPoint of oauth-login to the request url of the client (android) and handle it?